# How do I trigger an Azure function from another Azure Function

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-functions

I have a service bus triggered function, and would like to email the message to a specific recipient. I have already setup Sendgrid and tested a function that can send emails. I want to trigger this email function whenever a message arrives in the queue.

I have also setup all the required parameters for the queue.

Comment: Why not to make it in the same function? as Input service bus queue and for output send grid emails?

Comment: Thank you, it was what I ended up doing and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a HTTP trigger, or a storage queue trigger to initiate other functions.

If you use a webhook, and use the masterKey from `D:\home\data\Functions\secrets` by setting the authorisation to admin, you can ensure that only the masterKey can be used. (there is more at [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-http-webhook/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-http-webhook/#api-keys) )

Typically you would use a webhook if you need a response and a storage queue if you want a fire-and-forget (since you can't easily get a response into the calling functions execution)

This also gives you the ancillary benefit of being able to run functions in multiple languages without needing to worry about exchanging data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to decouple the entire functionallity you want to share including, including orchestrationtriggered and activitytriggered functions in a separated class; added with dependency injection; and then call it from your multiple functions.

Otherwise as other have suggested, the recommendation is or comunnicating with Queue Storage or using Logic Apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#cross-function-communication)